# How to replace substring with int

Tags: c

So i've seen alot of functions like str_replace(str, substr, newstring) but all of them won't work with numbers so i was wondering if anyone had one that would work with both chars and ints or just int ive been looking everywhere and cant figure out a idea on how to write my own.
my goal exactly is to be able to replace a string with a int value in the string not just string with string

below is the function i use to replace strings and it worked just fine

```
void strrpc(char *target, const char *needle, const char *replacement)
{
    char buffer[1024] = { 0 };
    char *insert_point = &buffer[0];
    const char *tmp = target;
    size_t needle_len = strlen(needle);
    size_t repl_len = strlen(replacement);

    while (1) {
        const char *p = strstr(tmp, needle);

        // walked past last occurrence of needle; copy remaining part
        if (p == NULL) {
            strcpy(insert_point, tmp);
            break;
        }

        // copy part before needle
        memcpy(insert_point, tmp, p - tmp);
        insert_point += p - tmp;

        // copy replacement string
        memcpy(insert_point, replacement, repl_len);
        insert_point += repl_len;

        // adjust pointers, move on
        tmp = p + needle_len;
    }

    // write altered string back to target
    strcpy(target, buffer);
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and add a [mre] to your question

Comment: What do you mean by replacing a substring with an int? Do you mean the string representation of the int?

Comment: If that's what you mean, just format the int into a string, then use the `str_replace()` function that takes strings.

Comment: Ive tried copying it to a string or type casting it to function and neither worked

Comment: Ugh, typecasting a number to a "string" sounds like recipe for disaster. Why don't you show what you have and what you are trying to do? All this wishy-washy "I've seen", "I've tried", "It works fine but" isn't going to lead anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn an integer into a string by "printing" it to a string:

```
int id = get_id();
char idstr[20];

sprintf(idstr, "%d", id);
```

Now you can

```
char msg[1024] = "Processing item {id} ...";

strrpc(msg, "{id}", idstr);
puts(msg);
```

But note that the implementation of `strrpc` you found will work only if the string after replacement is shorter than 1023 character. Also note the the example above could more easily be written as just:

```
printf("Processing item %d ...\n", get_id());
```

without the danger of buffer overflow. I don't know what exactly you want to achieve, but perhaps string replacement is not the best solution here. (Just sayin'.)